# Order of function calls -gRPC

Tags: netty, grpc-java

I am using gRPC (using java netty) in an application but It looks like the order of function calls has not been persevered. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the server to receive RPCs in the order they are sent by the client? gRPC doesn't provide that guarantee. If these RPCs may overlap, I am not sure what the ordering of the upstarts can bring you. If they may not overlap, then you can simply start next RPC after the previous one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need ordering, you could use a grpc stream, which guarantees in order delivery of each message sent on the stream.

An example of grpc stream in nodejs is below -

```js
call.on('data', (message) => {
  console.log(`[${message.sender}]: ${message.content}`);
  // Respond to the client
  call.write({ sender: 'Server', content: 'Message received!' });
});

call.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Client left the chat');
  call.end();
});
```