# Do I need to make my code thread-safe when replacing function calls by gRPC calls?

Tags: c++, multithreading, grpc-c++

I am splitting an application in two, and therefore replacing some C++ function calls by gRPC calls. The new modules can run on different machines or on the same one (even in the same process). Do I need a mechanism (e.g. mutex/locking) to avoid multithreading issues, which where not present before?

As I understand, the gRPC server uses thread-pools and may handle each request on a different thread. That basically opens up potential for multithreading issues. However, my client code is single-threaded, so **the second (gRPC) call is executed only after the first (gRPC) call has returned**. I am unsure whether this guarantees that ALL side-effects of the first call are visible to the second call, and everything still works as if it was run on a single thread. So far, the application seems to work fine without any locks, but that might just be "luck", as it often is the case with threading issues...

The only related question I found is [Order of function calls -gRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846923/order-of-function-calls-grpc), but that question does not specify how the client code is invoking the calls. And it also seems the poster can actually reproduce an issue, while my application seems to work fine so far

Comment: As long as you're not using the asynchronous mechanisms in the client, you shouldn't be having to deal with those issues.  If you want to use an asynchronous client, see See https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/async/   Even then, you can still do things with a completion queue and a single threaded client app. There maybe multiple threads overall, but you can still do all your application processing in a single thread. As long as none of your data structures have thread affinity....

Comment: @kalyanswaroop: I am not using the asynchronous API. And I am not using thread_local storage either (I am assuming this is the same as "data structures with thread affinity" - which would not make any sense in code that is not written for multithreading). So it looks like no locks are required in my case, according to your comment.